# Magento 2 How to add Banner attribute

Tags: attributes, adminform, banner-slider

Here I need to add a Banner attribute in Magento 2.
[image]

Here, On banner edit page I need to add an attribute, but I have no idea how to achieve it.
Can I get some help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you using mageplaza banner slider module ?do you want to add text attribute (column) ?

Comment: Thank you @Pawan for the response, Yes am using Mageplaza banner slider. I need a Dropdown attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always better to keep our customization in custom module, So I am creating a module which will:

- Add a custom column in table `mageplaza_bannerslider_banner` to hold value
- Add custom value to existing form
- Add source model to keep option values

> app/code/Pawan/MageBanner/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Pawan_MageBanner',
    __DIR__
);
```

> app/code/Pawan/MageBanner/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Pawan_MageBanner" setup_version="1.0.0" >
        <sequence>
          <module name="Mageplaza_BannerSlider"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> app/code/Pawan/MageBanner/Setup/InstallSchema.php

```
<?php

namespace Pawan\MageBanner\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{


public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface    $context)
  {
    $installer = $setup;

    $installer->startSetup();

    $eavTable = $installer->getTable('mageplaza_bannerslider_banner');

    $columns = [
        'custom' => [
            'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            'nullable' => true,
            'comment' => 'Custom',
        ],
    ];

    $connection = $installer->getConnection();
    foreach ($columns as $name => $definition) {
        $connection->addColumn($eavTable, $name, $definition);
    }

    $installer->endSetup();
}
}
```

> app/code/Pawan/MageBanner/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Mageplaza\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Edit\Tab\Banner">
        <plugin name="pawan_banner_form" type="Pawan\MageBanner\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Edit\Tab\Banner" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/Pawan/MageBanner/Plugin/Block/Adminhtml/Banner/Edit/Tab/Banner.php

```
<?php
namespace Pawan\MageBanner\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Edit\Tab;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Pawan\MageBanner\Model\Config\Source\Custom;

class Banner
{
    protected $registry;
    /**
     * Custom options
     *
     * @var Custom
     */
    protected $customOptions;
        
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        Custom $customOptions
        )
    {        
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->customOptions = $customOptions;
    }
      
    public function aroundGetFormHtml(
        \Mageplaza\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Edit\Tab\Banner $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    )
    {
        $banner = $this->registry->registry('mpbannerslider_banner');

        $form = $subject->getForm();
        if (is_object($form)) {

        $fieldset = $form->getElement('base_fieldset');

        $customBanner = $fieldset->addField('custom', 'select', [
            'name'  => 'custom',
            'label' => __('Custom Text'),
            'title' => __('Custom Text'),
            'values' => $this->customOptions->toOptionArray()
        ]);

        
            if($banner->getData()){
                $form->addValues($banner->getData());
            }
            $subject->setForm($form);
        }

        return $proceed();
    }
}
```

> app/code/Pawan/MageBanner/Model/Config/Source/Custom.php

```
<?php
namespace Pawan\MageBanner\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface;


class Custom implements ArrayInterface
{
    const SOME   = '0';
    const ANOTHER = '1';

    /**
     * to option array
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $options = [
            [
                'value' => self::SOME,
                'label' => __('Some value')
            ],
            [
                'value' => self::ANOTHER,
                'label' => __('Another value')
            ]
        ];

        return $options;
    }
}
```

**Note:**

- I have used `custom` as  a field name, you can change as per requirement
- Need to run commands like setup:upgrade, (if production- setup:static-content:deploy  setup:di:compile)
  **Hope above will help!**

Comment: Thank you @Pawan

Comment: welcome @PraveenNegimani